# Delete all Redis keys starting with a String using @CacheEvict

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, redisson, redis-cache

I am using Redis cache for caching (in a Spring boot application). I want to delete all keys starting with a Prefix String which is formed through the code and will look something like--> `ABC:env:userAppId:`
I want to drop all keys from Redis cache starting with that Prefix String.

I am passing the prefix String to the method that calls the Redis drop method:

```
void dropCache(){
//Calculate the prefix String

rediHelper.dropCache(prefixString) ;
}
```

The Redis Helper method looks like:

```
@CacheEvict(value= "user", key="#objectKey")
void dropCache(String objectKey){}
```

I already tried following and none of them worked:

1. Suffixing the * : @CacheEvict(value= "user", key="#objectKey*")
2. Using this approach:  @CacheEvict(value= "user", key="#{objectKey*}")

None of these have worked.

Also,

1. If this can be solved using @CacheEvict?
2. If not possible using @CacheEvict then how it can be achieved?